# How to Create an object with JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

How to create an object describing a person. The object should have the following properties :

- First name
- Last name
- Address (door number, street and city)
- A list (array) of phone number (mobile, landline and skype number).

the Output should be in following format:

- The textual representation of the JSON object above.

Comment: @PaulwinJerome see about `JSON.parse`

Comment: Assuming this is JavaScript in a browser, look into [the native `JSON` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_native_JSON).

Comment: can you please tell me how to get input from user for those name address objects? @Barmar

Comment: You can use `prompt()` to pop up an input box, or you can get it from `<input>` fields using `document.getElementById("inputID").value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var object = {
    firstName: "Joe",
    lastName: "Smith",
    address: "123 Main Street",
    phones: [ 
        {
        type: "mobile",
        number: "123-123-1234"
        },
        {
        type: "home",
        number: "321-321-4321"
        }]
};

var json_string = JSON.stringify(object);
```

If the JSON string is in `$json` in PHP, you can get the mobile phone number with:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($array['phones'] as $phone) {
    if ($phone['type'] == 'mobile') {
        echo $phone['number'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what the last line of code tells about??

Comment: It assigns the JSON string to a variable. You can use `console.log(json_string)` to display it in the Javascript console, or you can send it to a server using AJAX, etc.

Comment: what is the textual representation of those json object?? how can i display it?

Comment: I already told you, use `console.log()`.

Comment: how to use console.log() ??

Comment: You put it in your Javascript, then open the Developer Tools with F12. This is basic knowledge that any Javascript programmer should know.

Comment: but i'm a beginner . sorry

Comment: how to echo mobile number using php?

Comment: Added a PHP example to my answer.